# Compiled LINQ queries - NHibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Looking at this link shows me that compiled queries can be used to improve performance in Linq to SQL apps (I've seen other examples in Entity framework):

http://blog.linqexchange.com/index.php/how-to-use-compiled-queries-in-linq-to-sql-for-high-demand-asp-net-websites/

This requires a parameter that inherits DataContext - which I don't think NHIbernate has, but is the point of this question.

I have looked at these links:

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2389

[Compile NHibernate Linq expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597303/compile-nhibernate-linq-expressions)

but I don't see an up-to-date and definitive answer.

If anyone has the answers, I would love to hear them :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspecting the current NHibernate trunk, shows that NHibernate caches query plans for LINQ queries, so it is not necessary to explicitly compile queries for reuse. The only extra overhead is the calculation of the unique cache key for the LINQ expression.